# Meaning of the term "studies leading to a degree"

Tags: graduate-school, application, degree

I am slightly confused about the meaning of the term "studies leading to a degree" in an application form.

Does it mean only studies that lead to an actual degree, in which case incomplete studies that did not lead to a degree are not covered by this term?

Or does it denote any studies that were initially started as part of a degree program, irrespective of whether the studies were completed or a degree was awarded or not?

Comment: What is the usual context of the term?  If it's asked for in regard to current education, then it need not have been completed yet, as it's still in progress.  There are options that include college courses and college-like courses that do not lead to a degree, such as job training schools.  There's also nothing (that I can see, as I've never attempted it) stopping one from taking college courses that would normally be part of a degree program, while not being enrolled in a degree program.

Answer (score 1):

In every case I've seen, this term referred to coursework that was part of a degree curriculum, whether or not that was earned. I suspect this is because organizations can simply specify the degree itself if they need the latter distinction. However, without the actual context it's difficult to be certain.